# How to link a python file to another one?

Tags: python, tkinter

Let, I have two files -- main.py and temp.py.
All the codes are written on main.py in which there is a special btn as 'Hello', and basically it is an tkinter GUI.

I want that, when i cilck on 'Hello' btn it will execute a python temp.py and temp.py contains some code that will add or change a lebal, btn or any thing in main.py .

### The above is my assumption, but i don't know how to import properly a file in another and how to work on it.

What is have tried?

I basically import 'main' in temp file and create a label according to how it should execute in main.py file.
And in main.py I have use first time - os.system('python temp.py') and exec(open('temp.py')read())
And both time I get TclError - Null main Window.

Comment: A small sample of your code would help.

Comment: You need to import temp.py to main.py like "import temp" and then run a function located in temp from the main.py file. If the function is called "change_color" you would call the function temp.change_color(). As Derek said, a small of sample of your code would be useful.